# How to display text in center of page and that text animate after slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I am using bootstrap slider(https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/). I have to display text in center of page and that text should animate after slider.I tried some code for center but its not taking and please assist me for animation after slider.

**CSS**

```css
.carousel-caption {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-caption h1 { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Demo example at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/rrVPZd)**
and animate the content with `animate.css`

I hope it helps